# iterator parameter in generics function C#

Tags: c#, generics, iterator, ienumerable

I would like to do a convertAll generic a function like

```
public static Iout ConvertAll<Iin, Iout, T, TOutput>(this Iin source, Converter<T, TOutput> converter)
        where Iin : IEnumerable<T>
        where Iout : IEnumerable<TOutput>
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
            yield return converter(item);
    }
```

The problem is that visual studio tell me :

> The body of 'Sgd.CollectionExtensions.ConvertAll(Iin, System.Converter)' cannot be an iterator block because 'Iout' is not an iterator interface type

the things is I have the where clause so it should be recognize like an iterator, isn't ?

i also try :

```
public static I<TOutput> ConvertAll<I, T, TOutput>(this I<T> source, Converter<T, TOutput> converter)
        where I : IEnumerable
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
            yield return converter(item);
    }
```

but it says

> The type parameter 'I' cannot be used with type arguments

so i don't know what to do.
i don't want a function like :

```
public static IEnumerable<TOutput> ConvertAll<T, TOutput>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Converter<T, TOutput> converter)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
            yield return converter(item);
    }
```

it's much simpler and it's working but it return a IEnumerable an i want the same kind of iterator in output that i have in input

Hope you can help me 
Thanks

Comment: The compiler has no idea how to create whatever type parameter the user passed (eg, `ControlCollection`)

Comment: In particular, iterator types are compiler-generator types that _only_ inherit `IEnumerable<T>`.  `List<T>` cannot be an iterator.

Comment: @SLaks Or `IEnumerator<T>`; they can be either of those two.

Comment: @SLaks i don't understand i says that Iin is a ienumerable<T> so the compiler know ?

Comment: Why do you not what to use your third option `ConvertAll<T, TOutput>`?

Comment: @bobzer: What if I write `ConvertAll<ImmutableStack<T>>`? What should the compiler do?

Comment: @SLaks I would the compiler look what kind of iterator it has on the input and take it for the output. It's not possible ? i mean for generics it does inference all the time i though it was inference too

Comment: @Tory what do you mean ?

Comment: @bobzer I mean, why do you you not want to use `public static IEnumerable<TOutput> ConvertAll<T, TOutput>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Converter<T, TOutput> converter){foreach (var item in source)yield return converter(item);}`?

Comment: because i would avoid cast problem i would get same kind of list that i have in input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's say that you want the output to be a `List`.  `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.  Where are you defining the creation of a new list?  Where are you defining how a new item is added to the list?

You aren't.

`yield return` means that the constructed class will implement `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerator<T>`.  That's all it knows how to construct.  You can accept an input of something other than `IEnumerable<T>`.  You could accept an input of `List<T>`, for example.  But then again, you could do that even with your last function (the one you don't like), you don't need to use the earlier syntax to get that functionality.

You could add additional delegate parameters for the two operations you need (or really one, since you can add a generic constraint for creation).

```
public static TOut ConvertAll<TIn, TOut, T, TOutput>(this TIn source
    , Converter<T, TOutput> converter
    , Action<TOut, TOutput> adder)
    where TIn : IEnumerable<T>
    where TOut : IEnumerable<TOutput>, new()
{
    TOut output = new TOut();
    foreach (var item in source)
        adder(output, converter(item));
    return output;
}
```

Note that as a result of this you've lost all deferred execution though.

Comment: yes its true for List<T> but let's says i have a collection of entityCollection or controlCollection
i want to use this with entityCollection

Comment: @bobzer Same logic.  How will this method know how to construct it?  How will it know how to add an item to it?

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you mean

Comment: @bobzer What you're asking for isn't possible, because you haven't provided enough information in that method to do what you're requesting.

Comment: @bobzer Sure, just have delegates for that.

Comment: and still generics can you ellaborate a little bit please ? :-)